# Can't insert data via rest api

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I try using rest api in codeigniter to insert data.

I try this

```
    public function sensor_post(){
    $data = array(
                'sensor_id'   => $this->input->post('sensor_id'),
                'value'       => $this->input->post('value'));

    $insert = $this->db->insert('measurement', $data);

    if ($insert) {
        $this->response($data, 200);
    } else {
        $this->response(array('status' => 'fail', 502));
    }

  }
```

And call
       http://localhost/rest_iot/index.php/iot/sensor?sensor_id=1&value=37

I try this in post man and I get error like this. I think I've fill the value, why this is happend?

```
   <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
    <p>Error Number: 1048</p>
    <p>Column 'sensor_id' cannot be null</p>
    <p>INSERT INTO `measurement` (`sensor_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, NULL)</p>
    <p>Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/rest_iot/system/database/DB_driver.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 691</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending the data within the URL, you are sending it via GET. However your code is trying to receive data sent via POST.
I presume in codeigniter you can simply write the code as follows to receive it as GET:

```
        'sensor_id'   => $this->input->get('sensor_id'),
        'value'       => $this->input->get('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you are sending data via GET or POST ? Assuming that `$this->post('sensor_id')` you are looking for POST but sending via GET `sensor_id=1&value=37`.

Send data via POST method or... retrieve via GET

Answer (score 0):

You are missing input in your post fields.

```
public function sensor_post()
    {
        $data = array(
            'sensor_id'   => $this->input->post('sensor_id'),
            'value'       => $this->input->post('value')
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('measurement', $data);

        if ($insert) {
            $this->response($data, 200);
        } else {
            $this->response(array('status' => 'fail', 502));
        }
    }
```

This will work for you.

Comment: can you check it by print out post value using this. print_r($this->input->post()); exit;

Comment: I get array(2) {
["sensor_id"]=>
NULL
["value"]=>
NULL
}
Array
(
) and I already fill the value

Comment: you receive Null value in post data means their is some issue from API side. You didn't receive value from API side.